# Opencart / sage pay issue

Tags: php, paypal, opencart, integration, opayo

Hi i was wondering if anyone can help here or has experienced this scenario? Basically we have a client who we are doing an opencart site for selling cosmetics etc. The site is completed and linked to his IMA (sage pay) but there is an issue we need to try and resolve before we can go live.

A customer can order a product fine and it goes into the admin area as processing fine and into sage pay for authorisation fine.

The problem is that because the client doesnt have stock control linking to the website he doesnt 100% know if what he has sold on the website is actually in his warehouse.

My Question is, is there an Opencart solution / plugin which will allow him to somehow edit the order within the admin area, this may increase / decrease the order price (he may even contact customer for an alternative option) so products need updating aswell! How would this relay back to Sagepay of the amended pricing?

What can anyone suggest to be able to do this?

We are at a loss on how to go about doing this?

Many thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could use AUTHENTICATE as the originating transaction type, then AUTHORISE the transaction when the stock has been checked.

The advantage of this is you can AUTHORISE for 115% of the value of the AUTHENTICATE if the price should go up, or any amount below the original transaction.

You might also look at DEFERRED / RELEASE....